# How do I restore the ActionBar in 4.0+

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-tabs

I am maintaining 3 tabs in my Activity of app targeting Android 4.0+.

The problem is that when restoring the app Activity, the `ActionBar` doesn't restore to its original/required state (how do I do that?). That is, even without doing anything to the `ActionBar` (I don't add `Tabs` in restore), I can view the last Tab which was open but the `ActionBar` is empty!

This is how I am adding the Tabs:

```
ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
actionBar.newTab()
   .setText("Files")
   .setTabListener(new TabListener<TabFiles>(this, TabFiles.class.getName(), TabFiles.class));
```

Any help or pointer is highly appreciated.